# Legend overwrite with column

Tags: r, bar-chart, legend

I have a legend, but it overwrites with one of the columns in the barplot.

```
BOD<-matrix(c(2846,2397,4408,3563,2001,1713,4137,3197,136,107,307,203),
            nrow = 3, byrow = T)

colnames(BOD)<-c("BOD","BOD lọc","COD","COD lọc")
DT <- barplot(BOD,
              main="Do Thi BOD", 
              legend=c("<5 Nam","5-10 Nam",">10 Nam"), 
              beside = T)
```

[image]

Comment: Read `?barplot` and note the `args.legend` argument. Follow the link to `?legend` and read how to specify where the legend is drawn.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use `legend("topleft", …)` (assuming your question is to reposition the legend).

```
BOD<-matrix(c(2846,2397,4408,3563,2001,1713,4137,3197,136,107,307,203),
            nrow = 3, byrow = T)

colnames(BOD)<-c("BOD","BOD lọc","COD","COD lọc")
DT <- barplot(BOD,main="Do Thi BOD",beside = T)
legend("topleft",legend=c("<5 Nam","5-10 Nam",">10 Nam"))
```

Here is my plot:
[image: Plot with legend topleft]

---

**Edit:**
A more idiomic way of doing this will be using `args.legend` and `legend.text` within the `barplot` itself, such as

```
DT <- barplot(BOD,
              main="Do Thi BOD", 
              legend.text = c("<5 Nam","5-10 Nam",">10 Nam"),
              args.legend = list(x = "topleft"),
              beside = T)
```

[image]

Comment: For me it does not fail. You should at least give an error message. In addition, the legend help has much more information for you.

Comment: legend hasn't color with column!

Comment: @user3798177, so why on earth did you accept that answer? In order to add colors write your legend as follows: `legend("topleft", c("<5 Nam","5-10 Nam",">10 Nam"), fill = c("black", "gray70", "gray90"))`

Comment: Thanks all pro! i'm starter! :))

Comment: @user3798177, you're not obliged to accept an answer until it really meets your need or helps you solve the problem. Building on @joran's comment to your question, `args.legend` can also be useful here: `barplot(BOD, main = "Do Thi BOD", beside = TRUE, legend.text = c("< 5 Nam", "5 - 10 Nam", "> 10 Nam"), args.legend = list(x = "topleft"))`